# Is it possible to retrieve the active window process/title in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, gui, window

I need a solution for getting the current active (focused) window information on a Gnome 2 desktop. I'm mostly interested in the process running that window and window title.

Is it possible?

**SOLUTION:**

Getting window title:

```
xwininfo -root -children | grep $(printf '%x\n' $(xdotool getwindowfocus)) | grep -oEi '"[^"]+"' | head -1
```

Getting process name:

```
ps -e | grep $(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getwindowfocus)) | grep -v grep | awk '{print $4}'
```

or:

```
cat /proc/$(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getwindowfocus))/comm
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/), a versatile X window automation tool.

```
focused_window_id=$(xdotool getwindowfocus)
active_window_id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
active_window_pid=$(xdotool getwindowpid "$active_window_id")
```

(I don't know what the difference between focused and active is.)

(I thought [wmctrl](http://sweb.cz/tripie/utils/wmctrl/) could do this, but apparently not.)

Answer (score 57):

It is as simple as this:

```
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname
```

Good luck hope it works for you!

Answer (score 9):

Simpler (IMO) than OP's solution (i.e. without `ps`, `grep` and `awk`), to get the process name :

```
cat /proc/$(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getwindowfocus))/comm
```

Or if you want an end of line :

```
echo $(cat /proc/$(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getwindowfocus))/comm)
```

Comment: Yes, `cat /proc/` is nice (and arguably faster, since it doesn't involve grepping the whole `ps` output). I added it to solution in question body, so future users will be able to find it.

Answer (score 8):

I know the question is old, but I feel [`xprop`](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/xprop.1.html) also should be mentioned here. It's readily available under X. It can be either used in an interactive way:

1. type `xprop` and select the window you want using mouse cursor, then
2. `WM_NAME` gives you the title of the window, `_NET_WM_PID` gives the pid

Or you can directly tell `xprop` which window you need by passing `-id` or `-name` option. Using `awk` you can get the active window id and pass it back to `xprop` like that (taken from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1255231#p1255231)):

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root -f _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW 0x " \$0\\n" _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | awk "{print \$2}")
```

Finally, using Your Favourite Tool™ (e.g. `grep` or `sed`) you can grep-out the needed values. For example for `pid` the output of the above command can be piped to `sed`: `sed -nE 's/^_NET_WM_PID.*= ([0-9]+)/\1/p'`

Answer (score 6):

Try the xwininfo command, http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xwininfo.1.html, it definitely returns the window title and as far as process goes, well ...

X has assigned it an ID and become the parent PID of the window and would also conceal it by default, so, assuming that Gnome has NET_WM_PID supported, as this patch from 2001 indicates it has, http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-devel-list/2001-October/msg00238.html, then we can review this post, http://www.mail-archive.com/devel@xfree86.org/msg05809.html , where the author writes a short C program to convert Window ID into PID, voila.

Comment: But it seems that `xwininfo` requires me to manually select the needed window. I hoped for a way to get the focused window from bash.

Comment: Something as in, `xwininfo -root -children | grep -oEi 'Window id: (?[0-9a-zA-Z]+) | grep -oEi '(?0-9a-zA-Z)' -- edit: my finger slipped, my regex for window id was bad. check this other site for varying reference: http://www.davygoat.com/software/rizzle/How_it_works.html

Comment: This command only gives the "root" window id, and not the active one :(

Comment: As of 2022, `xwininfo -root -tree` will work