# xdotool and new terminal windows

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, xdotool

I recently discovered the amazing `xdotool` command and was going to make a bash-script to open four windows, resize, and reposition them for work.

Before, I could use the command `xdotool key ctrl+alt+t` to create a new terminal, but now when i try and use this command it simply just prints `^[^T` to the terminal... Is there some subtlety that I am missing with xdotool, and if so could someone please assist me? If not and this is just a bug, does anyone have any advice for opening new terminals through bash so I can create the script desired? Thanks in advance!

Note: I just discovered `gnome-terminal` command

Further Note: Also `xdotool key ctrl+shift+n` works, but for some reason ctrl+alt+t doesn't.. wierd

Most Furtherest Note: here is the script for those interested, some changes I might make in the future, adding an option for a path to open windows into (currently just does current window).

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal
sleep .1
id1="$(xdotool getwindowfocus)"
xdotool windowsize $id1 48% 50%
xdotool windowmove $id1 0 0
gnome-terminal
sleep .1
id2="$(xdotool getwindowfocus)"
xdotool windowsize $id2 48% 50%
xdotool windowmove $id2 0% 50%
gnome-terminal
sleep .1
id3="$(xdotool getwindowfocus)"
xdotool windowsize $id3 50% 50%
xdotool windowmove $id3 50% 50%
gnome-terminal
sleep .1
id4="$(xdotool getwindowfocus)"
xdotool windowsize $id4 50% 50%
xdotool windowmove $id4 50% 0%
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/909305/make-ctrl-alt-t-to-open-a-terminal-tab-if-any-terminal-was-open and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38867/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-active-window-process-title-in-gnome/81898#81898

Comment: You say "before, I could use the command..." .  Before *what*?  How long ago, and what did you change?  Did you eg. upgrade your system?